# How is L2 regularization derived?

Tags: probability, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, regularization

I just proved to myself why the regularization is added rather than multiplied to loss function.

I did so by taking the **MLE** formula...

$$argmax\sum log(P(x_{i}|\Theta ))$$

and since we know that **MAP** uses a prior belief distribution...

$$P(\Theta | x) = \frac{P(x|\Theta )P(\Theta )}{P(x)}$$

We can write **MAP** as...

$$argmax\sum log(P(x_{i}|\Theta )P(\Theta)$$

If we redistribute the logs, we can see that $log(P(\Theta))$ is the regularization terms, as shown below...

$$log(P(x_{i}|\Theta)) + log(P(\Theta))$$

but now I would like to show how L2 itself is derived. L2 is defined as...

$$\lambda \sum_{k}\sum_{l}W^{2}_{k,l}$$

which is the element-wise multiplication of the weights. Where did this equation come from? What values for $P(x_{i}|\Theta)$ and $P(\Theta)$, for example, do I need to use to derive this L2 formula? Can someone please explain it to me step-by-step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the prior $\mathbb{P}(\Theta)$ to be multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}_l(\mathbf{0},I),$ where $l$ is the dimension of the parameter $\Theta.$ $I$ is the $l\times l$ identity matrix.

[Here is a reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior)